# Firefox ESR 60.07 GPO can't open about:policies

Tags: group-policy, firefox

if I install the normal Firefox Version I can open the about:policies and everything looks fine but when I try this with the ESR Version, there is not such a module as policies. Can't find any of them in the whole browser. In about:support is "company policies" marked as "inactive". How can I activate the policie module?

Cheers

Comment: From what I can tell `about:policies` was introduced in version 63.

Comment: So there is no ESR Version available with this feature? But the GPOs should apply with 60.07?